# SmtpClient Send(Mail) function timeout error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send out an email to a mailing list that I have created, but when I run the function it just times out. I am not sure whether it is a host error or if I'm missing code or what. I am running an mvc format program on a local server.

I originally didn't have the credentials, but adding them changed nothing. Both before and after adding them all that happens is it loads for about a minute before reporting a timeout.

```cs
private void SendEmail(string sender, string[] attachments, List<string> recipients, ReleaseNotes notes, string username, string password)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.Subject = "Software Release of VCM Version " + notes.ReleaseVersion;
    mail.From = new MailAddress(sender);
    mail.Body = GetEmailBody(notes);
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    foreach (string r in recipients)
    {
        mail.To.Add(r);
    }

    foreach (string a in attachments)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(a));
    }

    client.Host = "pod51213.outlook.com";
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

I am supposed to see the email appear in my inbox while the screen switches over to a screen saying email was sent. Its not giving me an actual error code. It just says operation timed out.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Are you sure that your SMTP settings are set properly?

Comment: Don't you need to specify the port?

Comment: Try first sending the e-mail to one hardcoded recipient without attachments to see if it arrives at all.

Comment: Add `SmtpServer.Port = 587;`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the host I needed and get the function to run. The company I wrote the code for had their own host server. All I did to fix the code was delete the line that included client.Credentials, because I did not need that, and in the quotes for client.Host I replaced "pod51213.outlook.com" with "smtp.irco.com", which is the mail server for the company I built the program for.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should specify the port number

e.g.

```
SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587) // This for gmail
```